# Escaping % symbol in **gt** package function fmt_percent()

Tags: html, r, dplyr, gt

```r
library(gt)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
```

I'm using **gt** package to create a table with a column (b) in % format
whose HTML code I want to export to confluence

```r
example <- tribble( 
  ~a, ~b,
  0.4, 0.4)

example %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  fmt_percent("b")
```

However, when I export the HTML code of the table with function `as_raw_html()`,
the `%` symbol is turned into `&percent;`.

```r
example %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  fmt_percent("b") %>% 
  as_raw_html() %>% 
  str_detect("&percnt;")
#> [1] TRUE
```

Is there a way to avoid `%` symbol to be transformed into `&percnt;` in **gt**?

I found several ways to overcome the issue but I wonder if **gt** can take care of it.

```r
example %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  fmt_percent("b") %>% 
  as_raw_html() %>% 
  str_replace("&percnt;", "%") %>% 
  str_detect("&percnt;")
#> [1] FALSE

example %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  fmt_number("b", scale_by = 100, pattern = "{x}%") %>% 
  as_raw_html() %>% 
  str_detect("&percnt;")
#> [1] FALSE

example %>% 
  mutate(b = sprintf("%0.2f%%", b*100)) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  as_raw_html() %>% 
  str_detect("&percnt;")
#> [1] FALSE
```

I found an issue in **gt** github related to this problem:
[Feature request: have option of using literal % instead of ...](https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/686) but it seems still open.

<sup>Created on 2021-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You could get a copy of the package and replace those `switch(context, html = "&percnt;", latex = "\\%", "%")` in `gt:::context_percent_mark`

Comment: After doing `as_raw_html()` where are you using this?

Comment: @Ronak Shah, i.m using it to create a confluence web page through its API